# getJSON: NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, json

I wrote a code that uses **getJSON** (see below). FireBug returns the following error message:

```
"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://localhost:10088/test/myquery.php?query=SELECT%20tm%20FROM%20schedule%20WHERE%20val=%27BT009%27;"
```

I cannot figure out the reason of this error. Any help is highly appreciated.

PS I tested this SQL query in MySQL Query Browser. It has returned 3 rows.

**mainPage.php**

```
<script>
function updateList(){
   var query = "SELECT tm FROM schedule WHERE val='BT009';";

   $.getJSON(
           'myquery.php?query='+query,
           function(data) 
           {
               alert(data);
           }   
   );

}

$(document).ready(function() {
    updateList();
});

</script>
```

**myquery.php**

```
<?php
include_once 'include/connect_db.php';

if (isset($_GET['query'])) {
    $query = $_GET['query'];

    $condb = connectDB();
    $result=execute_query($query);
    closeDB($condb);

    $rows = array();

    if ($result && mysql_num_rows($result)) {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $rows[] = $row['tm'];
        }
    }   

    var_dump($rows);

    echo json_encode($rows);

} else {
    echo json_encode("Failed");
}
?>
```

Comment: Please don't use the `mysql_*` functions, they are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you want to learn, [here is a good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: This is not the answer to your question, but it'd be irresponsible of me not to mention it. You are generating an SQL string in JavaScript and sending it to your server for execution. That's a *very serious application security flaw* called SQL Injection. Don't do this. Really, really, *really* don't. Here's [information about it](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection) on the OWASP site.

Comment: What happens if I use the URL yourdomain.com/myquery.php?query="drop table schedule"?

Comment: @vascowhite or worse, dropping the entire DB.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer unfortunately I didn't know the db name otherwise I'd have done that :)

Comment: Or yourdomain.com/myquery.php?query="select * from users". Now I haz your passwordz!

Comment: Place `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors', true);` above `include_once` in _myquery.php_ and post the error message.

Comment: @mAu: I included these two lines above include_once. In this case FireBug does not show any message at all.

Answer (score 3):

An [Internal Server Error (Code 500)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error) is a server-side error and nothing to do with AJAX. This is usually caused by bad server-side code. You might want to check your syntax and also try viewing the page via the browser. The page may have printed some error details as well.

Comment: I wrote http://localhost:10088/test/myquery.php?query=SELECT%20tm%20FROM%20schedule%20WHERE%20val=%27BT009%27;" in Browser. The error message is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to venture a guess that the server is having difficulty understanding your query parameter. Try encoding it:

```
'myquery.php?query='+encodeURIComponent(query)
```

Like someone else stated, what you are doing is not secure. You should not be passing queries for a service to execute!

EDIT: Another possibility is that you aren't passing three arguments to $.getJSON(). Try:

```
$.getJSON(
   'myquery.php',
   {query: query},
   function(data) {
      alert(data);
   }   
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using firebug.Run the firebug when you are executing this code in the browser.It will give the cause of the error and also where the correction is required.Hope it will help.